How do I specify a field having keyword or fielddata=true in ElasticSearchIO?
We are using Apache Beam Pipeline and ElasticSearchIO in Java.  How can I make a field be a keyword or use fielddata=true?  Preferrably, we would like to use a keyword.  Thanks.
We tried the following code, and we want type to be keyword:
        pipeline.apply("Read MySQL data", JdbcIO.<ProgramProduct>read().withDataSourceConfiguration(config)
                .withQuery(sql).withOutputParallelization(false)
                .withFetchSize(readBatchSize)
                .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<ProgramProduct>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            public ProgramProduct mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                    return new ProgramProduct(resultSet.getInt("product_fk"), resultSet.getInt("program_fk"),
                            resultSet.getString("type"),
                            getProductConfig(resultSet.getDouble("price"),
                                    resultSet.getDouble("variable_min_points"),
                                    resultSet.getDouble("variable_max_points")),
                            resultSet.getString("date_created"));
                }
            })).apply("Apply transform on data", ParDo.of(new DoFn<ProgramProduct, String>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) throws SQLException {
                    ProgramProduct product = processContext.element();
                    String jsonObject;
                    if (null != product) {
                        jsonObject = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(product);
                        processContext.output(jsonObject.toString());
                    } else {
                        processContext.output(null);
                    }
                }
            }))
            .apply("Write to Elasticsearch", ElasticsearchIO.write()
                    .withConnectionConfiguration(ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration
                            .create(new String[] { elasticHost }, elasticIndexName)
                            .withApiKey(elasticApiKey))
                    .withMaxBatchSize(elasticBatchSize));

`
